# Cómo enviar un mensaje en la misma página con PHP?

Tags: php, html

Estoy desarrollando  en php con html deseo un LOGIN al un usuario o una clave incorrecta desde decirle al usuario que el usuario es incorrecto pero deseo hacerlo dentro del mismo login sin tener que enviar el mensaje en otra pagina como cuando le digo (   echo="Usuario incorrecto";   ) algo así como imprimir en un label.

```
    if ($filas > 0) 
{
    header("location:../WebHome.html");
} 
else 
{
    echo "Usuario incorrecto.";
}
```

Comment: Por favor tratá de redactar otra vez la pregunta y de ejemplificar un poco lo que estás queriendo hacer porque no se entiende.

Answer (score 1):

He realizado un ejemplo del que puedes guiarte como validar variables en un mismo fichero al procesar el formulario, esto consiste simplemente en validar que existan en el request.

```
<?php 
$is_valid_login = false;
$procesing_form = isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']); 
// Si llegan los parametros por post, quiere decir que estamos validando el 
//formulario
if($procesing_form){
    // Validamos que el usuario y la contraseña sean correctas
    if($_POST['username'] == 'test@mail.cl' && $_POST['password'] == 'asd123'){
        $is_valid_login = true;
        // acá lo podemos redirigir o instanciar una variable de sesión
    }
 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/test.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Correo" name="username"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Ingresar"/>
    <?php if($procesing_form && !$is_valid_login): ?>
        <p style="color: red;">El usuario y/o la contraseña son incorractas</p>
    <?php elseif($procesing_form && $is_valid_login): ?>
        <p style="color: green;">Usuario y contraseña correctos =)</p>
    <?php endif; ?>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

creo entender lo que deseas, aunque tu pregunta está muy mal redactada, espero la puedas corregir.

Según comprendo, tienes un formulario de tipo login y cuando la clave sea incorrecta mostrar un mensaje sin dirigirte a otra página, sino en la misma, obviamente, para eso debes tener un form con isset (te recomiendo le des una gogleada) y el mensaje puedes mostrarlo de la siguiente manera:

Esto va dentro del head del html

```
    <style>

    .estiloError {
      color: red;
      animation: estiloError 5s linear forwards;
        -webkit-animation: estiloError 5s linear forwards;      
    }

    @keyframes estiloError {
      0% { opacity: 0; }
      2% { opacity: 1; }
      98% { opacity: 1; }
      100% { opacity: 0; }
    }

      @-webkit-keyframes estiloError {

      0% { opacity: 0; }
      2% { opacity: 1; }
      98% { opacity: 1; }
      100% { opacity: 0; }

    }
  </style>
```

y después cuando haces la condición puedes colocar esto (por ejemplo si existe el email en la base):

```
$exists = email_exists( $email );

  if ( $exists ) 
  {
    echo "<div class='container'><span class=estiloError>Este Email ya se encuentra Registrado</span></div>";
  }
```

como puedes darte cuenta, usas la clase llamada estiloerror
así lograras mostrar un mensaje de error que tarda 5 segundos y desaparece.